# Is it correct to execute a function inside IF else statement?

Tags: javascript

The isCheck() function returns *false* if not radio buttons have been checked.

```
if (isCheck() === false) {
        i = 0;
        return i;
      }
```

Comment: If it is not _conventional_, could you suggest alternatives?

Comment: in my answer i show you an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wrong in executing a function inside if conditional statement.

For such case you can use [**ternary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var i=-1; // Note var key word & initialized with some value
  isCheck() === false ? (i=0):(i=someOtherVal)
```

Answer (score 2):

yes it works. alternatively you could use **[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**
using that syntax:

***test ? expression1 : expression2***

for example :

```
 //init var i with some value
 var i = 1;
 function isCheck(){ return false;}

 i = isCheck() === false ? 0 : i;
 return i;
```

or simple:

```
 //before you should initialize i
 return !isCheck()  ? 0 : i ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, some will say its not conventional but it should work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct

[image]

You dont need to create a variable only to receive a bool and later do a validation you can do directly.